# grails, how to force the browser to download a file

Tags: grails, download

In the controller, I do this to try to get the browser to download a file when the user clicks on a link:

```
    render( contentType: 'text/csv', text: output);
```

This works in Chrome, but does not work in IE or safari, they just show the data.  Also, it shows the file name as a number (which happened to be the Id on the url, such as www.me.com/show/1

Apparently. the way to fix the download is to convert to an octet stream. This can be done in a htaccess file, but Im not using apache.  Is there any way to do this in grails?  I would imagine its a common scenario.

In php, one might do this:

```
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.csv"');
```

Any ideas?

After reading the two repsonses below (may thanks!) this worked:

```
response.setHeader "Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=report.csv"
    response.contentType = 'text/csv'
    response.outputStream << output
    response.outputStream.flush()
```

The amazing thing is that I could take a string and use << to write it to the output stream. I was going to try to work out how to turn the string it something like a stream.

Comment: yes dude the same goes to when uploading and downloading an image file or when you want to preview or render image file our database itself and view it on your jsp ..use those below lines except the response.contentType = 'jpg/png' :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class DownloadController {
    def download(long id) {
        Document documentInstance = Document.get(id)
        if ( documentInstance == null) {
            flash.message = "Document not found."
            redirect (action:'list')
        } else {
            response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM")
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment;Filename=\"${documentInstance.filename}\"")

            def outputStream = response.getOutputStream()
            outputStream << documentInstance.filedata
            outputStream.flush()
            outputStream.close()
        }
    }
}
```

[refer this site for more](http://grails.asia/grails-example-application-save-documents-to-database/)

Comment: Is there a way to do both? Download the file and continue with the action?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this: http://lalitagarw.blogspot.com/2014/03/grails-forcing-file-download.html

```
class DownloadController {
    def downloadFile() {
    InputStream contentStream
    try {
    def file = new File("")  
    response.setHeader "Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=filename-with-extension"
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", "file-size")
    response.setContentType("file-mime-type")
    contentStream = file.newInputStream()
    response.outputStream << contentStream
    webRequest.renderView = false
    } finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(contentStream)
  }
 }
}
```